# how to open in new tab the pdf in virtuemart product?

Tags: php, html, pdf, joomla2.5, virtuemart

I have a pdf for every product in virtuemart and I would like to open the pdf in a new tab.

In virtuemart in Configuration/Shopfront i checked the box Show the pdf view icon.

Now I have found the line in html with firebug tool the`a href`  tag that I have to change but i can't find it in joomla files to add the `target="_blank"`atribute.

Comment: How you are attaching PDF to virtuemart product? Because if this is a plug-in then you need to make changes in plugin files..

Answer (score 0):

You probably need the file **components/com_virtuemart/views/productdetails/tmpl/default.php**

It would be better to copy this file and paste to **templates/your_template/html/com_virtuemart/productdetails/** and under the line

```
if (VmConfig::get('pdf_icon', 1) == '1') {
```

write something like

```
echo '<a href="'.$link.'&format=pdf" target="_blank">PDF</a>';
```